# GateKeeper Blocks codesinged application

Tags: macos, code-signing

I have a desktop application developed using Java Rich Client Platform framework. After creating .app bundle from Maven, I signed the application. I ran

```
codesign -dvvvv --deep amplide.app/
```

and below is the output

```
Executable=/Users/parastiwari/Downloads/Amplide.app/Contents/MacOS/amplide
Identifier=com.ampl.ide.rcp.product
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=408 flags=0x0(none) hashes=7+3 location=embedded Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=5a171d44997474f39a4e748fbdfd298deabebd69
CandidateCDHash sha256=ab9dff13d32d0e6f811daf1a66979af5ef73f95d
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
Page size=4096
CDHash=ab9dff13d32d0e6f811daf1a66979af5ef73f95d
Signature size=8931
Authority=Developer ID Application: AMPL Optimization Inc. (ZNNBG5892S)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=May 4, 2017, 10:24:01 PM
Info.plist entries=15
TeamIdentifier=ZNNBG5892S
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=1726
Internal requirements count=1 size=184
```

Similarly,

```
codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 amplide.app/
```

produces

```
amplide.app/: valid on disk
amplide.app/: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Finally,

```
spctl -a -t exec -vv amplide.app produces

amplide.app: accepted

source=Developer ID

origin=Developer ID Application: AMPL Optimization Inc. (ZNNBG5892S)
```

It seems that everything is okay. But when I try to launch the application, I get the warning message saying the application is downloaded from the internet. Could anyone help me what could be the wrong with my codesigned application?

Thanks, Paras

Comment: Thanks to whichever of you two added the codesign and spctl commands to this question. They enabled me to confirm my app was signed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. The system will **always** tell the user the first time they launch an app downloaded from the Internet (i.e. a quarantined app).

If your app were not properly signed for Gatekeeper, then the dialog would say it's not from an identified developer and would **not have an Open button**. The user would have to right- or Control-click on it and choose Open from the contextual menu to get a chance to launch the app.

You should try with an unsigned copy of your app to see the difference.